# javascript reload only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know javascript and I have tried to find an answer on this before posting.

```
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            location.reload(true);
        });
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
});
```

See the code in work here: http://jsfiddle.net/7duedzkb/5/

This code reloads a page every 5 seconds. I'd want to modify it to reload a page only once, basically it will reload the page after 5 secs and then stops the reload loop. I need this on a aggregator type of site where at first page opening the feeds are loaded from cache for speed issues.

Can you help? Much appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: use localstorage to know if the page has been reloaded once

Comment: The best way would be to do it server-side. Load this script only if you serve the page from cache.

Comment: Adam can you show an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must reload only if a certain condition is true. For example, you can save in sessionStorage a flag and read if exists don't reload.

```
var store = window.sessionStorage;
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    if(!store.getItem("reloaded")) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
               store.setItem("reloaded", "true");
               location.reload(true);
           });
       }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
    }
});
```

It's better session storage instead of localstorage, because the next time user comes to the page the flag will be setted.

### EDIT

Solution storing the URL of the page (assuming the URLs are unique):

```
var store = window.sessionStorage;
var page = window.location.href;
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    if(!store.getItem("reloaded-"+page)) {
       setTimeout(function(){
           $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
               store.setItem("reloaded-"+page, "true");
               location.reload(true);
           });
       }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks this works. If a user moves to another page will the script refresh again after 5s?

Comment: If the user end the session (close browser for example), the reload will produce again first time the user comes to page.

Comment: is it not possible to tweak the code so that the script refreshes after 5s on every page load without closing the browser? (for ex. if a visitor moves to another page, the feeds on that page will be loaded again from cache and this refresh would be needed) Thanks

Comment: That is a task more complex than your initial request. You can identify every page with an unique ID and set the session storage key with that ID. Then you can extend this functionality to all pages that you need.

Comment: is this the only way to do it? The site has more than 200 pages

Comment: If you identify all pages with an unique id, the functionality is simple. If not, you will waste a lot of time. This is a common problem: don't recopile all needed functionalities before start to develop the application.

Comment: Please, check this answer as correct answer since this solves the problem you are asking for. For a new question please, or ask a new question or edit this topic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104862/discussion-between-merxie-and-marcos-perez-gude).

Comment: how was lunch? have you got a minute?

Comment: Yes, I enter in chat

Comment: Hi Marcos! Have you got a moment to enter chat? Thanks

Comment: I have a new question for you :) Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36033392/how-to-hide-all-posts-within-a-folder?noredirect=1#comment59718003_36033392

Comment: Marcos is there a way to modify this code and run the script only on specified pages in a var? At the moment it runs on the pages which are not added to var hiddenpages. https://jsfiddle.net/bnc1urxx/1/ Can you help? Thanks!

Comment: Hello! Are you there?

Comment: You can use the `in_array()` phpjs function, you can store all pages in an array and then with `in_array()` you can see if it's included or not, and if it's included, run the script. See the code for `in_array()`: http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array/

Comment: I think you don't try by yourself. At least with no efforts. What about this? https://jsfiddle.net/xm2ckvdf/1/ . So easy, I spent 1 minute.

Comment: Thanks, it took too long for me without a result!

Comment: I suggest you need to learn some basic javascript to achieve simple things without desperation. With that you'll achieve great things without external help. However, we are here to help all users, but next time open a new question, because we need to grow reputation and new questions / answers will be useful for other users

Answer (score 1):

Use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) for this purpose,

```
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    if(localStorage.getItem("reloaded") !== "true") {
    //Check the flag in localStorage before begin the reload.
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            localStorage.setItem("reloaded","true");
            //set a flag during the first reload in localStorage
            location.reload(true);
        });
      }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
    }
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7duedzkb/7/)

Or Use [SessionStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) as pointed in the below comments, based on your req :-

```
var storage = window.sessionStorage;
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    if(!storage.getItem("reloaded")) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            location.reload(true);
            storage.setItem("reloaded", "true");
        });
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
    }
});
```

Comment: `sessionStorage` is more propper.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Then the page will be reloaded again if user reopens the browser.

Comment: Yes, OP said: `I need this on a aggregator type of site where at first page opening the feeds are loaded from cache for speed issues.` That's a good reason to use session not local

Answer (score 1):

set the flag in a cookie and check it everytime before doing a reload

```
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            if ( getCookie("reload") != "true" )
            {
               setCookie("reload", "true"); 
               location.reload(true);
            }
        });
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
});

    function setCookie(key, value) {
        var expires = new Date();
        expires.setTime(expires.getTime() + (1 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        document.cookie = key + '=' + value + ';expires=' + expires.toUTCString();
    }

    function getCookie(key) {
        var keyValue = document.cookie.match('(^|;) ?' + key + '=([^;]*)(;|$)');
        return keyValue ? keyValue[2] : null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I haven't seen your answer until now for some reason. Is there a way to make this script run only on certain pages?

Comment: Can you help with my question?

Comment: @merxie sure. You can check for the current page url before executing the script.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    if (localStorage.reloaded !== 'true') {
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
                localStorage.reloaded = 'true';
                location.reload(true);
            });
        }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
    }
});
```

Comment: `sessionStorage` is more propper.

Answer (score 0):

Use SessionStorageto achieve the result, please see the below sample:-

```
var storage = window.sessionStorage;
$(function(){
    $('body').fadeIn(1000);
    if(!storage.getItem("reloaded")) {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('body').fadeOut(2000, function(){
            location.reload(true);
            storage.setItem("reloaded", "true");
        });
    }, 5000); // 5 seconds for demo
    }
});
```

[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/7duedzkb/9/)

Comment: `sessionStorage` is more propper.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude _localStorage is the same as sessionStorage with the same same-origin rules applied **but it is persistent**_. From the docs.

Comment: @Jai 
 
Yes, OP said: `I need this on a aggregator type of site where at first page opening the feeds are loaded from cache for speed issues.` That's a good reason to use session not local

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude if such case then what is the use of `location.reload()` then.

Comment: Maybe it's a weird trick to reload and check the new server values that can be setted in background while the page doesn't reloads. The system that he uses I don't know, and I don't think is the best way or not, but for the exact question, the correct answer should be with session storage. You are free to have a different opinion.

Comment: the sample doesn't refresh after 5s or is it just me?

Comment: now it works. it is same as the other code from Marcos. This script wont refresh if visitor moves to another page.