# How to hide all posts within a folder?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, url-rewriting

I have created a var to hide some pages from a jquery task. Ex:

this will hide the page "hidden" - "http://domain.com/hidden/"

how to hide all posts within this folder without adding them all one by one?

"http://domain.com/hidden/post1"

"http://domain.com/hidden/post...n+1"

Can anyone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: strange question, have you heard about url rewrites?

Comment: I'm not a coder. No haven't.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to htaccess redirect this long url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20047745/how-to-htaccess-redirect-this-long-url)

Comment: Bonatti - it is a different question!

Comment: You can use the duplicate to solve the same problem. You must rewrite your urls. If a user enter in `domain.com/hidden/post`, you can rewrite to `domain.com/post.php?hidden=true`, and then read the `$_GET['hidden']` to know if it's a hidden post or not. This is a server-side solution, for a client-side solution you must attach more details. We don't know why you need to hide some posts and how to make it, because what is the purpose of this kind of hidings?

Comment: You can use this site to know what regular expression you can use: http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: @Marcos it is related to your help with previous script. I want to add all posts with /hidden/ in the url to the var=hiddenpages. Possible?

Comment: It's possible to do, but I don't understand how.